# Can an irreducible representation have a zero character?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

I asked the following question on Stackexchange,

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978407/can-an-irreducible-representation-have-a-zero-character

but it got no answer, so I ask it here.

Is there an example of the following situation : $F$ is a field, $G$ is a finite group, $\rho$ is an irreducible $F$-representation of $G$ (with finite degree) and the character of this representation takes the zero value at every element of $G$ ? If I'm not wrong, $F$ cannot be algebraically closed (Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, 8.1.9, p. 220) and must have a nonzero characteristic $p$ such that the degree of the representation is divisible by $p$ and such that $G$ is not a $p$-group (Robinson, exerc. 8.1.5, p. 222). But that doesn't solve the problem. Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Regarding "but it got no answer": You got 10 upvotes, which indicates much interest from the readers, but more importantly you only asked this yesterday. I think that it is good practice to wait at least three days (actually, I would suggest one weak), so that the mathematics sites don't have unnecessary duplicates. By the way, that's an interesting question.

Comment: The cross-post immediately gave rise to useful answers, so it sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 16):

Well, it seems that the character of an irreducible representation of a finite group over whatever field is always nonzero. I find this statement in I.M. Isaacs, Character Theory of Finite Groups, coroll 9.22, Dover, p. 155.

Comment: This is a precise reference for the result (and more).  The corollary itself depends heavily on the earlier Lemma (9.12) where the field is assumed to be a *splitting field* for the group: here the representing matrices span a full matrix algebra, where the character can take value 1.   [I suspect the general result goes back to Burnside's work, though Isaacs' book does not emphasize the history.]

Answer (score 11):

Representations of *semigroups* whose characters are identically zero  have been classified in

*A. Freedman, R. N. Gupta, and R. M. Guralnick*, [**Shirshov’s theorem and representations of semigroups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1997.181.159), *Pacific J. Math.* (1997), no. **181**, 159--176.

Their result is the following, see Theorem 2.5 in the aforementioned paper:

> **Theorem.** Let $\rho \colon S \to \mathrm{End}(V )$ be a finite irreducible representation
>   of the semigroup $S$ and  let $A$ be the $F$-algebra generated by $\rho(S) \subseteq  \mathrm{End}(V )$.
>
> Then the character $\chi$ of $\rho$ is identically $0$ if and only if $A \simeq M_r(D)$, where
>   $D$ is division ring such that either $Z = Z(D)$ is not separable over $F$ or
>   $\mathrm{dim}_Z(D)$ is a multiple of the characteristic. In particular, if $F$ is perfect, the character in nonzero.

${}$
**Edit.** As explained by B. Steinberg in the comments below, none of the conditions in the previous Theorem can occur when $S$ is a *finite* semigroup. In particular, when $G$ is a finite group over any field $F$, the character of any irreducible $F$-representation of $G$ is non-zero. This agrees with the result in Isaac's book quoted in Panurge'a answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning Group Theory with Robinson's book as textbook and I must confess that your answer is difficult to understand for me. May I ask if I understood correctly the satement of I.M. Isaacs that I quoted in my answer and if it agrees with the result quoted by you ?

Comment: I checked Isaac's result, and it seems to me that you quoted it correctly. So it appears that none of the situations in Friedman-Gupta-Guralnick theorem can occur when the semigroup $S$ is actually a group.  However I'm not a a specialist in the area, so I do not see immediately why this is true. Maybe some more  expert user can explain this.

Comment: It can occur for infinite groups and semigroups but not finite ones. Look at my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819466/the-division-algebras-arising-in-the-wedderburn-decomposition-of-a-finite-group which proves it doesn't happen for finite semigroups.

Comment: The paper you cite gives infinite groups. The multiplicative group of a not "nice" field extension.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: So this agrees with Isaac's claim, good. Thank you.